# UIPrintInteractionController in landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, printing, landscape

I'm trying to print a PDF document pulled from a web server from my iPad app.
The document is in landscape (proved with Preview) but the UiPrinterInteractionController prints the document in portrait mode.

I set `printInfo.orientation = UiPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;` but it doesn't seem to help.

I try to print the document to the Printer Simulator. When I go into the folder where the documents are saved, I got to documents. One, the original file, one the printed one.

The original file is in landscape and oriented the right way. But the second one, the print output, is in portrait and the borders are cut.

Any ideas?
Thanks for help, Julian

Comment: I tested printing with another printer. When I take one of the _InkJet_ printers instead of _Laser_ it just works like charm! Unfortunately I got no AirPrinter so I can't test for real. Does anybody knows this issue though?

Answer (score 1):

Salute,

I guess we can rotate PDF data manually before sending it to printer.

Here is some code below (sorry actually not really tested) which I hope could be helpful (not sure it is a best solution but anyway). Make sure that "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" is imported.

```
- (NSData *) prepareForPrinting:(NSData *) data
{
    NSData *result = nil;
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    if (pageRect.size.width > pageRect.size.height) 
    {
        GLuint w = pageRect.size.width;
        GLuint h = pageRect.size.height;
        pageRect.size.width = h;
        pageRect.size.height = w;
        CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
        CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
        CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);
        int numPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);

        if (numPages > 0)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) 
            {
                page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i + 1);
                CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
                CGContextRotateCTM(pdfContext, M_PI_2);
                CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -pageRect.size.width);
                CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
                CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid PDF");
        }
        CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
        result = [NSData dataWithData:(NSData *)mutableData];
        CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
        CFRelease(mutableData);
    }
    else
    {
        result = data;
    }
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. It is a workaround for some people, for sure! But my problem is, that one printer prints it the right way and another one prints it wrong… I think it's a printer issue and theres no way to fix

Comment: Hi, yes I faced your problem in simulator with working InkJet and not working Laser. Actually tried to print on real world printer and no luck, landscape pdfs are still not rotated to fit the paper. So, I tried not to relay on printInfo.orientation as it  doesn't work fine and rotate content of doc before printing and it worked well. Now all my pdfs are printed in a correct orientation on paper and Laser simulators as well. But maybe I missed something and it is not what you need..

Comment: No, it just sounds like exactly, what I need. So you set the printer orientation to portrait  (or leave it like it is) and then manually rotate the pages content to landscape? That sounds really easy… I just couldn't see the wood for the trees… Thanks for the idea!

Comment: One more question: Does your code (`CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1)`) handles just one page? So do I have to use a for(){} loop? How do I combine the pages back to one document, if so?

Comment: Salute, the code you pointed is just for getting a rect to know page content orientation and when it's width > height we get to for loop where you draw all pages `page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i + 1);`. Regarding orientation option so it is not assigned and left by default as portrait.